# Why is it an invalid method declaration when I am passing parameters?

Tags: java

```
    public class Store {
  // instance fields
  int area; 

  // constructor method
  public Calc(int one, int two, int three) {
    area = one*two*three;  
  }

  // main method
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sideOne = 2;
    int sideTwo = 3;
    int sideThree = 1;

    Calc mult = new Calc(sideOne,sideTwo,sideThree);

    System.out.println(mult.area);
  }
}
```

Can anyone help a beginner understand why, when passing parameters, this is an invalid method declaration?

Comment: You define/call a `Calc` constructor, but there is no `Calc` class.

Comment: The constructor name should match the class name

Answer (score 2):

You define/call a `Calc` constructor, but there is no `Calc` class.

Rename your class to `Calc` ant your code will compile and execute correctly:

```
public class Calc {
    // instance fields
    int area;

    // constructor method
    public Calc(int one, int two, int three) {
        area = one * two * three;
    }

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sideOne = 2;
        int sideTwo = 3;
        int sideThree = 1;

        Calc mult = new Calc(sideOne, sideTwo, sideThree);

        System.out.println(mult.area);
    }
}
```